# Can kafka subscribe on a MQTT topic

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt, iot

I have a MQTT broker running on a raspberry pi, i can publish and subscribe to  topics.

But i would like it if Kafka could subscribe to one or multiple MQTT topics.
Can somebody help me please?

Comment: What have you already tried and what research have you done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do that.

- First of all you need to set up Kafka and zookeeper (here is the official apache kafka [installation guide](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart)) (here is [the official zookeeper installation guide](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperStarted.html#sc_Download))
- You need a kafka plugin to act as an MQTT source connector (you can use this one [evokly/kafka-connect-mqtt](https://github.com/evokly/kafka-connect-mqtt)
  )
- After compiling the source, you need to configure the plugin (indicate the MQTT topic, username, password, MQTT broker IP) (here is an [example of the configuration](https://github.com/evokly/kafka-connect-mqtt/blob/master/config/mqtt.properties))
- Restart kafka server and start the Kafka MQTT source connect
- start a kafka consumer that will subscibes to the kafka topic that you configured and retrieve messages (you can refer to [this quick example](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_consume)) or you can develop your own consumer (here is an example how to develop your own kafka consumer [Kafka Consumer in Java](https://www.devglan.com/apache-kafka/apache-kafka-java-example))